# why cannot define same local label in multiple functions?

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86-64, gnu-assembler

Want to define same local label in multiple functions:

```
    .text
    .globl main
func:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
.a:
    leave
    ret

main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
.a:
    leave
    ret
```

Strangely get error:

```
$ clang -c main.s
main.s:13:1: error: invalid symbol redefinition
.a:
^
```

When I was using yasm it allowed same local labels in multiple functions.
Do you have any clues?

Comment: have you tried compiling with `as` instead of clang to test?

Comment: In some assemblers you prefix "@" (or "@@") before the labels to make them local, so you can use the same label many times ("@@mylabel").

Comment: Try using `1:`, `2:`, etc. as done with GNU as. Look [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.19/as/Symbol-Names.html) for more information.

Comment: This SO answer may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14506296/3857942

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike NASM, `.label` isn't local to the function (actually preceding non-`.` label) in gas syntax.

`.Llabel` is a "local" symbol name, meaning it doesn't go in the symbol table.  It's still visible throughout the file, so [the GNU `as` manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html) doesn't call it a local label.

---

There *are* local labels in gas syntax, but they're not function scoped.  (See the above link).  You *have* to use forward/back annotations to references them, otherwise they're numeric constants instead of labels.  (e.g. `mov $1, %eax` puts a literal 1 into eax, not the address of the most recent `1:`).

More importantly, you can't give them meaningful names, like `.Lcopy_loop` or `.Linput_non_zero`.  They're useful inside macro definitions, or in inline asm that might be inlined into multiple places or otherwise duplicated by the optimizer.  Otherwise **meaningful names should be preferred**.

```
func1:
    test
    jcc 1f    # you need the forward/back annotation, otherwise it's an absolute address to jump to.
    ...
1:
    ...
    ret

func2:
    test
    # jcc 1b    # BAD!!! jumps to 1: in func1, which is still in scope.  This could bite you after moving some blocks around but missing the f/b annotations.
    jcc 1f      # good: will jump forward to the next definition of 1:
    ...
1:
    ...
    ret
```

It may be better to just write `func1.a` or `func2.a`.

---

On some targets (not including x86-64 and i386), there are restricted-scope local labels that let you avoid accidentally jumping to the wrong definition of a label, but you still can't use meaningful label names:  See **Dollar Local Labels** on the same page of the manual (link above).

`1$:` is a syntax error in gas and clang, for x86 targets.

That's unfortunate, because it would be function-scoped, unless you use any labels with meaningful names inside your functions (like `.Lmain_loop:`).

Comment: I read the manual too. Do you have any tips/good habits of using labels instead of using numeric labels?

Comment: @BulatM.: it's basically the same principle as making up variable names or `static inline` helper-function names in C.  Usually the name should either describe why you go there (`.Linput_was_zero`), or what the block there does (`.Learly_out`), or something like that.

Comment: @BulatM. My most successful strategy so far has been prefixing meaningful label names with with `.L + function name + __`.  The problem I ran into with just `.L + meaningful name` was that I often end up copying code around, which creates conflicts, given the unfortunate globalness of the labels. While the strategy does not eliminate them, it makes them trivial to fix with a quick regex substitution to replace the prefixes in a given source text range.