# subq $8 %rsp segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

I'm learning to code in x86-64 assembly (AT&T) on Linux (gcc) and couldn't find a solution to my segmentation fault in this trivial code. I've seen some questions referring to stack alignment; however, this fails even when I try $8 or $16:

```
.global main
main:

    #prologue
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #initialise base pointer

    #reserve memory for subroutine
    subq    $8, %rsp   #the line causing the segfault

exit:
    movq    $0, %rdi
    call    exit
```

My other programs I´ve written seem to work fine after a call to printf. What is wrong with the above code? The code fails with or without the call to exit. This and the code below is failing. I compile using:

```
gcc -o test test.s
```

The entire code:

```
.text
formatStr: .asciz "%ld"
resultStr: .asciz "The result is: %d\n"
q1: .asciz "Enter the base: "
q2: .asciz "Enter the exponent: "

#qTable2: #look up table for correct string during scanf
#   .asciz q1
#   .asciz q2

qTable: #alternative look up table
    .quad base
    .quad exponent

    base:
        movq $q1, %rdi
        ret
    exponent:
        movq $q2, %rdi
        ret

###################
# Subroutine:   pow
# Function: Power an integer base to an exponent
# Inputs:   uint base, int exponent(natural)
# Outputs:  int result
##################
pow:
    #prologue
    pushq   %rbp    #store caller base pointer
    movq    %rsp, %rbp

    movq    $1, %rax    #reset result
    movq    $0, %rbx    #initialise loop    
    loop1:
        imulq   %rdi
        incq    %rbx
        cmp %rsi, %rbx  #compare loop interator to exponent
        jle loop1           

    #epilogue
    movq    %rbp, %rsp  #clear local variables from stack
    pop %rbp    #restore caller base pointer
    ret

.global main
###################
# Subroutine:   Main
# Function:     Application entry point
###################

main:

    #prologue
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #initialise base pointer

    #reserve memory for subroutine
    subq    $8, %rsp

    #Gather the inputs from the user
    movq    $0, %rbx    #loop counter

#inputAcq:
    #Call printf using correct question
    movq    %rax, %rsi  #move result into argument 2
    movq    qTable(,%rbx,8), %rdi   #format string as argument 1
    call    *%rdi
    movq    $0, %rax    #no vector registers
    call    printf

    leaq    -16(%rbp,%rbx,8), %rsi  #Argument 2 
    movq    formatStr, %rdi #Argument 1
    movq    $0, %rax    #no vector registers
    call    scanf       

    incq    %rbx    #increment loop counter

    cmp $1, %rbx    #check if more inputs are necessary else continue
    jl  inputAcq

    #Call pow
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rsi  #the exponent
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rdi #the base
    call    pow

    #Call printf
    movq    %rax, %rsi  #move result into argument 2
    movq    $resultStr, %rdi    #format string as argument 1
    movq    $0, %rax    #no vector registers
    call    printf

#exit program without errors
exit:
    movq    $0 , %rdi
    call    exit
```

The error for the main code when using (gdb) x/i $pc:

```
0x4004e5 <exit+7>:  callq  0x4004de <exit>
```

Comment: What is the rest of your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @sigjuice: `[mcve]` in a comment expands to [mcve].  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000 for other magic comment markdown, like `[ask]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exit:                   # target of the CALL instruction
    movq    $0 , %rdi
    call    exit
```

You've written an infinite loop that includes pushing a return address.  It eventually segfaults when you run out of stack.

Use a different name for the `exit` label in your own code.  `.Lexit` would work, and wouldn't show up as a label when debugging.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602313/why-cannot-define-same-local-label-in-multiple-functions/39603975#39603975) for more about local labels in GNU as syntax.

Comment: The code was plagued with other segmentation faults. But that one was the dumbest. Started learning how to use gdb properly to help find my errors quicker. gcc -g at least gives me the line number that causes the fault when running gdb which is why gdb seemed so cryptic to me. But both your comments helped thanks!

Comment: Note that my answer is also correct (in fact it's more correct given the original question): the actual faulting instruction is `callq  0x4004de` (which tries to push return address onto (now exhausted) stack). You could remove the `subq $8, %rsp` entirely, and you'll still get the fault.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: yeah, totally agree.  No idea why anyone downvoted it.  I upvoted it while it was still the only possible answer to the question (before the edit).

Comment: @Johann: See also the bottom of the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for gdb tips

Comment: Thanks, I'm definitely going to study that wiki. Already found some interesting topics! @EmployedRussian I wanted to upvote yours but don't have enough rep, since this was my first question. I inadvertently induced different segfaults when trying to reduce my code to a minimal example. This was my first major leap away from the comfort of IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

> `subq    $8, %rsp   #the line causing the segfault`

Since the instruction above does not reference memory, there is *no way* that segmentation fault is happening on *that* instruction.

You are likely mis-interpreting what you actually see. You should

1. show a minimal example, complete with build commands, and
2. show how you arrived at "the line causing the segfault" conclusion, so your mistake can be pointed out.

P.S. To find the *actual* instruction on which the segfault happens, run your program under `gdb` and execute `(gdb) x/i $pc` command once the segfault actually happens.

Comment: When I compile either blocks of code I receive the error <exit>. Without the exit in the simplified code, I receive another error 0x0: Cannot access memory at address 0x0. I've also updated my code above.

Comment: @Johann: If you don't do something to exit, then the CPU just keeps executing whatever is in memory.  A string of all-zero bytes happens to decode to a dereference of RAX, if I recall correctly.  That's where the `Cannot access memory at address 0x0` comes from, which you'd see if you used the disassembly feature of your debugger.  (e.g. `layout asm` / `layout ret`.  See the bottom of the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info))