# How does `_L_lock_%=` become `_L_lock_432` in glibc?

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I'm reading the glibc source code, trying to debug a deadlock.

In my stack trace, I see:

```
#0  0x00007ff58b449eec in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ff58b3bda31 in _L_lock_423 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ff58b3bbca8 in __GI__IO_link_in () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ff58b3bab92 in __GI__IO_file_init () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

But looking through the code, the only reference to `_L_lock_` is in the macro `lll_lock` in `lowlevellock.h`.

There I see a string inside an inline assembly statement:

```
".type _L_lock_%=, @function\n"
```

This somehow becomes the function `_L_lock_423` in my call stack. Where does the `423` appear from? What is the `%=` notation? what does %= mean in assembly?

Comment: https://locklessinc.com/articles/gcc_asm/ GCC inline ASM. The '%=' operand prints a unique numeric identifier within the compilation region. This is helpful for constructing a unique symbol from within an inline asm.

Comment: This is the reverse question of [Labels in GCC inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898435/labels-in-gcc-inline-assembly), where `%=` is one of the answers, and the question is the problem that `%=` solves.  Not exactly a duplicate, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#AssemblerTemplate):

> ‘%=’ - Outputs a number that is unique to each instance of the asm statement in the entire compilation. This option is useful when creating local labels and referring to them multiple times in a single template that generates multiple assembler instructions.